# How can I manipulate the grid layout spacing between rows in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm a freshman student in college and my professor said I could get out of the midterm if I coded a calculator app using Android Studio. I'm working on the layout right now and want to make it look nice. How can I manipulate the margins between rows so there isn't any?

[Here's the link to the image of the layout and what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owU0Q.png)

Comment: I know it's not the answer you are looking for, rather advice: don't use RelativeLayout and GridLayout. Those are obsolete and problematic. 
Better approach, would be to use here LinearLayout: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear 
Best approach will be using ConstraintLayout: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to the button views within the GridLayout.

Comment: Using android:layout_margin? I only know basic C++ so this is entirely new to me. Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: yup. try adding that to each of the buttons.

Comment: Yeah that didn't seem to work, I'm trying to get rid of the gap between all of the buttons. If I set the margin to 0dp it doesn't change it at all. If I set the margin to a positive dp it just increases the space between them.